# Obtener datos de un ckeckbox

Tags: php, array, checkbox

Tengo este array que me muestra las asignaturas de un módulo. Ahora bien, quiero que una vez seleccionadas las matriculas que quiera, al presionar un boton, se muestren las opciones del checkbox que he escogido. ¿Como se podria hacer?

```
$modulos = $GLOBALS['cf'][$_SESSION['cf']];

            foreach ($modulos as $key => $value) {
              echo "<input type='checkbox' name='moduloConfirmado' value='' >$key";
              echo "<br>";
            }
```

Comment: Lo que quiere es obtener las materias que allá seleccionado el usuario a través del `checkbox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente genera un Array en el `name` del `input`

```
foreach ($modulos as $key => $value) {
    echo "<input 
                 type='checkbox' 
                 name='moduloConfirmado[]' 
                 value='$key' >$key";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Puedes ver el Array que te genera con los checkbox seleccionados en PHP con

```
print_r($_POST['moduloConfirmado']);
```